# Advanced SQL Database Administration Training Class

Tags: sql-server

Can someone please suggest a good in-class (4-5 days) advanced SQL database administration training class?  For example, below is the link for beginner or intermediate SQL administration training.  I am looking for advanced training.  We are doing the same basic database administration work at my current work and I am not learning anything advanced.

http://www.learningtree.com/courses/2108/sql-server-database-administration/

Any help in suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Is there a particular database you're looking to do administration on? Your question seems really broad otherwise.

Comment: HI Kassandry, thanks for the response. I have been working with SQL Server 2012 for last 3 years.  I am familiar with usual DBA concepts such as backup, recovery, high availability, failover cluser instance, index management, user logins, security, encryption, etc. Since I have been doing all these for past 3 years, I need to learn something new in the world of SQL server administration. I want to learn advanced SQL DBA stuff such as performance tuning, wait stats, mastering execution plans,  etc. It would be great to go to 4-5 days in-person training class to learn from the experts. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The MCM videos are still available here: https://www.sqlskills.com/sql-server-resources/sql-server-mcm-training-videos/

Comment: Hi ooutwire, thanks for the response. Performance tuning classes seem very interesting. I will do some more research on them. Thanks.